# Jmeter unable to record actions on Mobile app on emulator

Tags: performance, android-studio, jmeter, performance-testing, mobile-application

I have done the below mentioned steps to record action from Emulator on Jmeter:

1. HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder port has been set to 8181
2. Emulator proxy settings has been set to port 8181 and IP as the machine ip where mothe emnulator and jmeter is running.
3. CA Cretificate has been installted in both jmeter and emulator.

Once i start the recording and start doing some actions i am getting the below exception in jmeter and no action is captured:

2021/02/11 16:56:23 WARN  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy: [60352] Problem with SSL certificate for '142.250.183.42'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
2021/02/11 16:56:23 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy: In SSL request, unable to find host and port in CONNECT request: [2404:6800:4009:827::200a]:443

Answer (score 0):

You have mismatch between HTTP protocol versions:

- `142.250.183.42` - stands for [IPv4 address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4)
- `2404:6800:4009:827::200a` - stands for [IPv6 address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address)

I think you need to align them, in case of JMeter you can [force the JVM to use IPv4 addresses](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html) by launching JMeter as follows:

```
jmeter -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

In order to make the change permanent add the next line to *system.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up.

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Hi Dmitri, i have tried the steps mentioned but i am still getting the same error. the fun part is the IPs printing in the logs is not of my machine.                                                                                  jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy: [64884] Problem with SSL certificate for '216.58.203.42'? Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown 
2021/02/11 18:07:17 ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy: In SSL request, unable to find host and port in CONNECT request: [2404:6800:4009:80f::200a]:443